# Row grouping in Ag-Grid

Tags: ag-grid

Is it possible to do row-grouping in `ag-grid` and having the similar look and feel of column grouping:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can refer following link 
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping-headers/

ex: 
`gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    {
        headerName: "Athlete Details",
        children: [
            {headerName: "Name", field: "name"},
            {headerName: "Age", field: "age"},
            {headerName: "Country", field: "country"}
        ]
    },
    {
        headerName: "Sports Results",
        children: [
            {headerName: "Sport", field: "sport"},
            {headerName: "Total", columnGroupShow: 'closed'},
            {headerName: "Gold", columnGroupShow: 'open'},
            {headerName: "Silver", columnGroupShow: 'open'},
            {headerName: "Bronze", columnGroupShow: 'open'}
        ]
    }
];`